# input[type="submit"]:hover is not working using html and css, also not able to give input to input fields

Tags: html, css, input, submit

html code:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 51%;
  color: #4caf50;
  border: 1px solid #4caf50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="submitError"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="signMeUp" />
  </div>
</div>
```

styles for different types of input. not able to type anything in input fields dropdown is not working even after having 3 options

```
input[type="text"],
select,
input[type="password"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="email"] {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }
```

html flow for above css:
**body->div->div->form->div->div->input**

Comment: I made your html and css runnable in your question. Seems fine. So what is different between this and your actual code?

Comment: You can use classname in input tag to use styled css

Comment: @epascarello nothing.. :-o its working here but not in my browser dont know why.. Thanks alot

Comment: So something else is overriding it. Inspect the element and figure out what is attached to it. You can force hover state so you can see what is applied. It is impossible for us to guess what is causing your problem.